# working with String[] args in java

Tags: java

I am trying to convert command line arguments from String to an array of Integer using an ArrayList (to account for a variable number of arguments. I'm sure its some bonehead mistake, but what am i doing wrong? I'm sure there is a much easier way to do this...

incase you are wondering my current command line input is: 3 5 7

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AddNumbers {
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ArrayList<Integer> integerArgs[];
    Integer temp;
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
        temp = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
        integerArgs.add(temp);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you compile and run this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
ArrayList<Integer> integerArgs[];
```

An `ArrayList` is not an array, and `integerArgs[]` is only applicable for arrays. Although this is "valid", it is likely not what you want. What it says is "create an array of `ArrayList`s". What you mean to do is

```
ArrayList<Integer> integerArgs;
...
integerArgs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

And you may want a more meaningful name, such as `intList`.

However, if your goal is to convert strings *that are known to be ints*, into ints, you could use [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)):

```
int[] ints = new int[args.length];
for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)  {
   ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
}
```

To be safe, you should try/catch the conversion, in case bogus (non-integer) parameters are provided:

```
try  {
   ints[i] = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
}  catch(NumberFormatException nfx)  {
   throw  new NumberFormatException("Cannot parse parameter index " + i + ": \"" + args[i] + "\"");
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList<Integer> integerArgs[];` is perfectly fine syntax. It just isn't what the OP wants.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Oh. An array of `ArrayList`s. Thanks. Fixing.

Answer (score 3):

First, you don't need `integerArgs` to be an array of `ArrayList`s, just an `ArrayList`.  Second, create the `ArrayList`.  Change

```
ArrayList<Integer> integerArgs[];
```

to

```
ArrayList<Integer> integerArgs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
ArrayList<Integer> integerArgs[];
```

This declares an **array** of `ArrayList` objects. Is this really what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Here is your code corrected, you had numerous syntax errors:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class AddNumbers
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        ArrayList<Integer> integerArgs = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i++)
        {
            Integer temp = Integer.parseInt(args[i]);
            integerArgs.add(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Added just for fun, Lamda style (requires Java 8):

```
Stream<String> stream = Arrays.asList(args).stream();
List<Integer> list = stream.map(c -> Integer.parseInt(c)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The Java 8 syntax is still a bit verbose compared to LINQ.  Hopefully 3rd party libraries will help simplify this in the future.